# Input для подтвержения sms-кода

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Не могу найти примеров реализация инпута для подтверждения кода через sms. Визуально выглядит так: 3 или больше инпутов, которые взаимодействуют таким образом, что при наборе 2-3 символов фокус переключается на другой, и если символы стираешь фокус переключается на предыдущий инпут. Хотел бы увидеть такую реализация на JQuery

Comment: Хотел бы увидеть Вашу реализацию.

Answer (score 3):

Если быстро и коротко то, например, так.

```js
$('.number_input').on('keyup', function(e) {
  let value = $(this).val();
  let len = value.length;
  let curTabIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('tabindex'));
  let nextTabIndex = curTabIndex + 1;
  let prevTabIndex = curTabIndex - 1;
  if (len >= 2) {
    $(this).val(value.substr(0, 2));
    $('[tabindex=' + nextTabIndex + ']').focus();
  } else if (len == 0 && prevTabIndex !== 0) {
    $('[tabindex=' + prevTabIndex + ']').focus();
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="number"] {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="number_input" type="number" max_n=2 tabindex=1>
<input class="number_input" type="number" max_n=2 tabindex=2>
<input class="number_input" type="number" max_n=2 tabindex=3>
```

Answer (score 2):

Немного исправленная форма под себя, если кому надо

```js
$('.sms-input:first-child').focus();

$('.sms-input').on('keydown', function(e) {
  let value = $(this).val();
  let len = value.length;
  let curTabIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('tabindex'));
  let nextTabIndex = curTabIndex + 1;
  let prevTabIndex = curTabIndex - 1;
  if (len > 0) {
    $(this).val(value.substr(0, 1));
    $('[tabindex=' + nextTabIndex + ']').focus();
  } else if (len == 0 && prevTabIndex !== 0) {
    $('[tabindex=' + prevTabIndex + ']').focus();
  }
});

$('.sms-input:last-child').on('keyup', function(e) { 
  if($(this).val() != '') {
    $('.signin-sms__wrap').addClass('done')
  } 
})
```

```css
.signin-sms__wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  padding: 5em;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
.signin-sms__wrap input {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 23%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 80px;
  font-size: 2em;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
.signin-sms__wrap input:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.signin-sms__wrap.done {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="signin-sms__wrap">
  <input class="sms-input" type="tel" maxlength="1" tabindex="1">
  <input class="sms-input" type="tel" maxlength="1" tabindex="2">
  <input class="sms-input" type="tel" maxlength="1" tabindex="3">
  <input class="sms-input" type="tel" maxlength="1" tabindex="4">
</div>
```